# Send an email with SendGrid and C# .NET Core 3.x

Tags: c#, .net-core, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email with SendGrid (Nuget package v. 9.15.1) in C# and .NET Core 3.1

I have a project that I use it as Nuget package where I have the logic to send an email. In my ConsoleApp I'm using this package. When I try to send an email, I can debug until when I invoke `SendEmailAsync`. After that the application stops.

```
SendGridResponse rtn = new SendGridResponse();

SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
message.From = new EmailAddress(request.FromAddress, request.FromName);
message.AddTo(new EmailAddress(request.ToAddress, ""));
message.Subject = request.Subject;
message.PlainTextContent = request.PlainTextContent;
message.HtmlContent = request.HtmlContent;

try
{
    Response response = await _client.SendEmailAsync(message);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        rtn.StatusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;
        rtn.Message = "Email sent";
    }
    else
    {
        rtn.StatusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    rtn.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    rtn.Message = ex.Message;
}
```

In the `Output` window I only can see that:

> 'ConsoleApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
>
> 'ConsoleApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Projects\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SendGrid.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The program '[14896] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Of course I can't tell for sure based on the information, but one possibility is that you are deadlocking. If anything in the call stack blocks an async call this can happen. Are you using `.Result` or `Wait()` anywhere in the call chain?

Comment: Oh, you are totally right. I didn't pay attention to that. Thank you